# Extracting information from a log file for aggregation

Tags: linux, shell

Given a log of the following format

```
2009-11-11 13:13:44,716 INFO Something happened : problem description . Waited 3 seconds
2009-11-11 13:23:44,716 INFO Something happened : problem description . Waited 1 second
2009-11-11 13:33:44,716 INFO Something happened : some other problem description .
```

How can I extract just the strings which are between `:` and `.`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe:

```
<logfile sed -e"s/^.* : \(.*\) \..*/\1/"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat logfile | cut -f1 -d. | cut -f4 -d:
```